# C: what does realloc do with memory that it frees up?

Tags: c

I have a toy C program that uses `malloc` and `realloc` to allocate and then deallocate memory:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int *ptr, i , n1, n2;
    printf("Enter size: ");
    scanf("%d", &n1);

    ptr = (int*) malloc(n1 * sizeof(int));

    printf("Addresses of previously allocated memory: ");
    for(i = 0; i < n1; ++i)
         printf("%p\n",ptr + i);

    printf("\nEnter the new size: ");
    scanf("%d", &n2);

    // rellocating the memory
    ptr = realloc(ptr, n2 * sizeof(int));

    printf("Addresses of newly allocated memory: ");
    for(i = 0; i < n2; ++i)
         printf("%p\n", ptr + i);
  
    printf("%d\n", *(ptr + n2 + 1));

    free(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

It takes a size, `n1` that it allocates and then a size `n2` that it reallocates. This program also, assuming `n1 > n2`, prints out the value at `ptr + n2 + 1` just to see what the deallocated memory is set to.

On my Mac, using `cc`, the value I get back from `printf("%d\n", *(ptr + n2 + 1));` is `0`.

Is that compiler-specific? Does realloc always set memory that it no longer uses to 0 after a realloc?

Comment: It does the same thing `free()` does -- releases it for re-use. Attempting to access the value at the address after it has been freed is *Undefined Behavior*.

Comment: when it does that, does it set values to 0?

Comment: Some malloc() implementations have the option to "poison" (eg. fill it with a pattern like `0xdeadbeef`) the memory freed with free() or realloc(), to help debugging use-after-free bugs.

Comment: @user414777: Indeed, but I think filling with zeros would be counterproductive in that regard as it's *not* a readily identifiable bit pattern.  So I doubt this is a feature of that kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's compiler-specific. Merely dereferencing a pointer that has been `realloc`ed is undefined behavior in standard C, so there are certainly no guarantees about what value might be there, if you get as far as seeing one at all.

In fact, I'm skeptical even that your compiler is intentionally zeroing this memory, unless you've set debug options to request that. Many malloc implementations store their own bookkeeping data in freed blocks, and it could be that the bookkeeping data stored at that location just coincidentally happens to be zero in this particular situation. But systematically zeroing freed memory (that will be reused by the process) would normally be a waste of CPU cycles as the user's code is not supposed to access that memory again, hence it is normally not done.

Actually, now that I look at your code, you never wrote anything into your allocated block in the first place.  So it's very possible that it contained zeros all along.  It is normal for memory freshly allocated by the OS to be zeroed (which ensures that it does not contain sensitive data from other processes), and so malloc'ed memory will *sometimes* be zeroed if it came directly from the OS instead of from a previously freed block.